# Is there a way to install java on Oracle 11g XE?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I am using the database Oracle 11g Express Edition (XE) and when I try to create a java source object it returns me an error:

> ORA-29538: Java not installed

The source code is simple:

```
create or replace and compile java source named hello AS 
  public class Hello {
    public static String hello() { return "Hello!"; }
  };
```

I found at Oracle's documentation that Oracle XE does not include Java.

Does anybody know if it is possible to "install" Java on it ?

Comment: It's a pity that Java is not available; half the time, however, what you want to do is possible in PL/SQL anyway. What exactly do you want to do (apart from returning static strings like `Hello!`)?

Comment: I'd need to deal with images, which is possible with ORDSYS (Enterprise Version) or using a java class.

Comment: If you're stuck with XE, an option would be to do image processing outside the database (e.g. Perl scripts, Python, or something). You can still store/retrieve images as blobs in the database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, [Java support is not available in Oracle Database 11g Express Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#BABDDIAE), and since the database itself does not have Java support, there is no way to extend it by installing Java yourself.

Comment: Awesome: crippleware. :{

Answer (score 1):

And if you have the full licensed version of Oracle, and need to install the JVM in Oracle, you can invoke as sysdba:

```
 @?/javavm/install/initjvm.sql
```

and you may also need to run

```
 @?/rdbms/admin/catjava.sql
```

The website https://itkbs.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/how-to-install-java-in-oracle-database-ora-29538/ taught me the first part; I still had errors with a Java class `schedFileWatcherJava` not found, which the second script fixed.

You can verify if Java is installed with this query from that website:

```
select comp_name, version, status from dba_registry;
```

which will list `JServer JAVA Virtual Machine` as part of the results if Java is installed.