# ORA-29538 Java not installed in SQL Developer running on Oracle 11g XE

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

cannot create any java objects on sql developer

I'm running Oracle XE 11g and SQL Developer Version 4.1.0.17

The error message is

```
ORA-29538: Java not installed
29538. 00000 -  "Java not installed"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to use a Java command when Java is not installed.
*Action:   Install Java, or do not use the command.
```

Comment: Try installing java?

Comment: how? JDK is already installed in the system

Comment: Well the error message is saying that it isn't installed, likely an environment variable or something isn't correctly set. For things like this, normally reinstalling the "missing" program fixes things. So, try re-installing Java. If that doesn't fix the issue, I don't think there really is much else that we can suggest. We don't know your setup and what other things you have tried.

Comment: Java is not installed on oracle 11g XE and you can't install it. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043042/is-there-a-way-to-install-java-on-oracle-11g-xe

Answer (score 3):

The express edition of the database does not include a JVM.  Therefore, you cannot create Java stored procedures in an express edition database.

If you need to create Java stored procedures, you'd need to get a different edition of the database.  Depending on what you are doing, you may be able to use the standard or enterprise editions of the database using the OTN license without paying a fee.