# PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_JAVA.SET_COMPILER_OPTION' must be declared in oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle

**Load Java into Oracle, I get this error**

```
C:\OracleJava>loadjava -user MTNIS/password@localhost:1521:xe -thin -grant
 -verbose SDIUser.java
arguments: '-user' 'Username/***@localhost:1521:xe' '-thin' '-grant' '-verbose' 'SDIUser.java'
created  : JAVA$CLASS$MD5$TABLE
creating : source SDIUser
loading  : source SDIUser
created  : CREATE$JAVA$LOB$TABLE
Error while creating source SDIUser
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 75:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_JAVA.SET_COMPILER_OPTION' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 75:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 1, column 239:
PLS-00201: identifier 'NameFromLastDDL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 231:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

The following operations failed
    source SDIUser: creation (createFailed)
exiting  : Failures occurred during processing
```

**This is how SDIUser.java looks like**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;

public class SDIUser {

    public SDIUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // Create
    public static void insert(String col1, String col2, String col3,
            String col4, String col5, int col6, int col7, int col8, int col9,
            int col10, int col11, int col12, String col13) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO SDI_USER_DIR VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, col1);
            pstmt.setString(2, col2);
            pstmt.setString(3, col3);
            pstmt.setString(4, col4);
            pstmt.setString(5, col5);
            pstmt.setInt(6, col6);
            pstmt.setInt(7, col7);
            pstmt.setInt(8, col8);
            pstmt.setInt(9, col9);
            pstmt.setInt(10, col10);
            pstmt.setInt(11, col11);
            pstmt.setInt(12, col12);
            pstmt.setString(13, col13);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.err.println(sqle.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void update(String col4, int col11) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "UPDATE SDI_USER_DIR SET col_1 = ?"
                + "WHERE col_11=?";
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setString(1, col4);
            pstmt.setInt(2, col11);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
            System.out.println("Done");
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.err.println(sqle.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void delete(int col11) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM SDI_USER_DIR WHERE col_11 = ?";
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setInt(1, col11);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.err.println(sqle.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void deleteAll() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM SDI_USER_DIR";
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
            System.out.println("done");
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.err.println(sqle.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void fetchAll() throws SQLException {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM SDI_USER_DIR";
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");
            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3)); 
            }
            conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.err.println(sqle.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

#### Note that the class is using "jdbc:default:connection" instead of the normal Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); and connection

#### DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID","username","password");

Comment: You appear to be using the Express Edition (XE) [which does not include Java in the database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC117).

Comment: Thank Alex Poole, is there anyway round it, or maybe I can install java in the Express Edition

Comment: [It doesn't look like it, no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13043042/266304). (Slightly curious that `loadjava` is present; but I guess you can use that from the XE home to load Java into a remove SE/EE database.)

Comment: thanks Alex Poole..