# Oracle 11g Database Missing Loadjava Utility

Tags: sql, oracle, loadjava

I read few tutorials regarding how to make Oracle SQL trigger to call Java method as [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/loadjava-tool.html#GUID-B80B4492-55BB-4B75-919C-6E5962380710).

Everywhere it is mentioned that there is command line utility called `loadjava`. I am using windows 10, oracle SQL server 11.2.0. I couldn't find anything named `loadjava`. So where do I get it? Also, how do I make a trigger in oracle sql that will call java method as soon as any table insertion happens?

Comment: Check if you use `Express Edition` - this edition has [no java support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13043171/4808122)

Comment: Yes, I am using a free SQL edition. I think it should be express edition. So is there loadjava cmd utility in the paid version?

Comment: Yes, so it is..